# Python logging module does not save to the filename specified?

Tags: python, logging

I need to distribute an application written in Python as an exe which will be installed in the Program Files folder of the user's computer. Since Program Files is by default write-protected, I need to save any files into the %APPDATA% folder on Windows. And I am doing that - I have the settings.ini, settings_db.db and another file created there.

However, it seems that the logging module in Python refuses to save its log there, and instead saves it to the root directory instead. This is the code I have:

```
currentPath = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "\\tools\\"

if not os.path.exists(currentPath):
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.environ["APPDATA"] + "\\tools\\")
        currentPath = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "\\tools\\"
    except:
        currentPath = os.getcwd()

if not os.path.exists(currentPath + "ubc.log"):
    open(currentPath + "ubc.log", "w").close()

print currentPath + "ubc.log"

#Let's define the logging "manager" as well as logging format...
logging.basicConfig(filename=currentPath + "ubc.log",
    format='%(asctime)-15s: %(name)-18s - %(levelname)-8s - %(module)-15s - %(funcName)-20s - %(lineno)-6d - %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger("gui-log")
```

The `print` statement above returns the correct result, gives me `C:\Users\Bogdan\AppData\Roaming\utools\ubc.log` . The `os.path.exists()` part successfully creates the file if one does not exist. But the logger just won't log there - it instead logs to the file in the directory from which the `.py`script has been executed.

Not sure if it matters, but before I had the `filename="ubc.log"`, and it did log to that file, but when the need arose to distribute this application, I changed that.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I bet the `except` is "eating" some exception. Try to run the code without the `try...except` and see what happens.
Also, it's generally better to use `os.path.join` et al. to manage path names.

Comment: How are you testing this code. Are you running with an interpreter that has a debugger, like Pyscripter or Pythonwin, for example?

Comment: And you don't need the open() stuff to create the file.  logging will take care of that for you.

Comment: @Bakuriu: ran it without `try/except` block, same problem. Also tried replacing it with `os.path.join()`. Another odd thing: when I try to open the file using same params (so I do `open(currentPath + "ubc.log", "r").read()`, it displays the contents of the file I manually put there.

@MikeHunter: thanks for the tip, didn't know it automatically created it. I am running it through the regular python interpreter. What's odd is that users have reported that it works fine after I "compile" it into an exe file, but I'd still like to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Well, I suspect there's something in the interpreter that's conflicting with your logger.  I've had this happen a lot when testing, and I have to run from a cmd window to make the logger work. Maybe that's not your problem, but it may be.

Comment: Reading `basicConfig` and `getLogger` docs it's not clear why you would expect `logger` to write to that file. You are setting a filename only for the root logger, not for the one you actually use. I wonder if the code you use when you build the .exe uses the root logger instead(and thus works).
Try to create the `'gui-log'` logger and manually set the handler and formatter.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I tried `logging.info("Hello World!")`, and the problem still persists. It still writes to the `ubc.log` file in the directory in which the script is at, and I can confirm that is a root logger (since it logs `%(name)` as well). I will try to manually set the handler and formatter.

Comment: Well, I am an idiot. So far it is a given: if you have a weird problem, you're probably an idiot. I imported some old modules which had already defined `logging.basicConfig` as the one in root directory. Thanks for the help you two, and, err, patience.